# Populating a many - many doesn't populate, and throws no errors

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, discord.js

My database looks like this:

> Table: Guilds -> guild_id, guild_name, guild_owner, guild_owner_id, guild_member_count, guild_prefix.
>
> Table: Members -> member_id, member_name, member_disc
>
> Table: Guildmembers -> guild_id, member_id, warning_points, chat_points

So `guild_id` and `member_id` are the values from Discord and are both PK's. My aim is to tie each member to a guild specifically, to add `warning_points` and `chat_points`.

I can populate both the `Guilds` table and the `Members` table, however, it doesn't auto-populate the `Guildmembers` table with the relevant data.

Upon trying to populate the table with this code:

```
let guiMemSQL = 'INSERT INTO Guildmembers(guild_id, member_id) SELECT Guilds.guild_id, Members.member_id FROM Guilds INNER JOIN Members ON Guilds.guild_id = Members.member_id'
con.query(guiMemSQL, (err, result) => {
    if(err){ throw err }
    console.log(`Updated GuildMembers Table`);
})
```

I get no errors. The table doesn't populate either. So either there is a flaw in my code/logic or I have not understood what I am doing correctly.

The information I am trying to get is `guild_id` and `member_id`, they are `BIGINT`s.

Comment: I don't work with MySQL but I don't think `BIGINT` would work for `guild_id` or `member_id`, when used in your code you always need to pass them as strings so why store them as numbers?

Comment: If you just execute the `SELECT` against your database does it return what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

mysql will not auto-populate a many-many table, you have to `INSERT` the values as you would any other table. The way I did this was with the below code:

```
// Update GuildMembers Table
let guiID = MemberInfo.userGuildID;
const memGuiID = BigInt(guiID); // Convert String to Number
const updGMT = {guild_id: memGuiID, member_id: memIdNo };
let guiMemSQL = 'INSERT INTO Guildmembers SET ?';
con.query(guiMemSQL, updGMT, (err, result) => {
    if(err){ throw err }
    console.log(`Updated GuildMembers Table`);
})
```

The use case of parameterised queries here, although not question specific are important to help combat the risk of `sql injection` attacks. And would be seen as good practise.

If anyone does know of a way to get the fields to auto-populate, please share!.

Currently I shall leave what I did to resolve this, In case others have a similar issue.